# Get post id in a function when edit/add a post

Tags: php, posts, functions

I am new to PHP and I am working in WordPress. I wrote a function in the functions.php file. My function is to update a custom field based on another field on the page when the user adds or edits a post. I am having trouble getting the post id in my function. How can I get the Post Id? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my function:

```
  function get_postid() {
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
  }

  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'get_postid' );

  function set_post_sort_order() {
    /* Get post id */
    $post_id = get_postid();

    
    /* Does object exist */
    if ( !$post_id ):

        /* Get which product taxonomy is selected. */
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'product' );
        $sort_order = 2;

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) :
          foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( $term->name == 'blah blah' ) :
                $sort_order = 1;
            endif;

            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_order', $sort_order );
          } 
        endif;

    endif;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your function `get_postid()` does not return anything. It should return the id:

```
function get_postid() {
    global $post;
    return $post->ID; 
}
```

2. If you are going to use the `$post_id` I guess your first `if` statement is wrong, because the `$post_id` should be evaluated to `true` not `false`. So it should be like this: `if ( $post_id ):`

Comment: Thank you Had1z for pointing out the error in my code. That actually solved my problem.